# Why not seeing shell globs as a "dialect" of regex?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, wildcards, terminology, syntax

I often confuse Bash 3.x shell globs:

```
?      # Match any single character.
*      # Match any string of characters (up until the asterisk).
[set]  # Match any character in set (but not the entire set itself).
[!set] # Match any character not in set.
```

with regex (especially [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)).

My question is why not seeing these as "Bash regex" (just as we have "JavaScript regex" for example)?

Why not seeing these as just another "dialect" of regex?

Of course it would be unorthodox, but I'm not sure there isn't any formal-logical reason not to.

Comment: Because bash has a completely different way of dealing with *actual* regular expressions.

Comment: I know it interprets them differently, but we can philosophize and say it treats two types of regex differently, can't we?...

Comment: At a very abstract level, one could philosophize that globbing, BRE, ERE, etc. are simply different pattern matching "languages"

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I didn't find a wiki article for ERE, what did you mean there?

Comment: @user9303970  ERE=Extended Regular Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filename globbing patterns and regular expressions have a syntax overlap, to some degree, but they work in fundamentally different ways.

The regular expression `e` will match (in) the string `hello` while the filename globbing pattern `e` would not. Globbing patterns are implicitly anchored, so the glob pattern `e` would be equivalent to a regular expression looking something like `^e$`, but their application may be different (the regular expression would match against a complete line in a text, whereas the glob pattern would typically match against a single filename).

Filename globbing patterns also don't have any special characters that qualifies the previous expression, such as `*` or `?` in a regular expression, or any facility to group parts of expressions as `(...)` does in a regular expression, or to alternate between possible sub-patterns as `|` does in a regular expression. Some shells obviously add some of this, as `bash` does with `shopt -s extglob` enabled, for example.

Globbing patterns have different use from regular expressions. Regular expressions are *primarily* used for selecting/matching strings from texts, whereas filename globbing patterns are *primarily* (but not exclusively) used for matching filenames or generating lists of existing names from a directory. Globbing patterns are used to match *strings* in e.g. `case ... esac`, but a POSIX shell never uses regular expressions for generating lists of names from a directory, unless *extended* with that capability.

Both types of patterns are defined by the POSIX standard:

- Regular expressions and their grammar is specified in [Chapter 9 of the POSIX Base Definitions volume](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09)
- Patterns used for filename expansion are defined in a few sections in the [Pattern Matching Notation section of the Shell Command Language chapter of the Shell & Utilities volume](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).

Of globbing patterns, the standard starts out by saying

> The pattern matching notation described in this section is used to specify patterns for matching strings in the shell. **Historically, pattern matching notation is related to, but slightly different from, the regular expression notation described in XBD Regular Expressions**. For this reason, the description of the rules for this pattern matching notation are **based on** the description of regular expression notation, modified to account for the differences.

There are several "dialects" of regular expressions, such as PCRE which you mention, but filename globbing patterns can not really be said to be one of them.

There are several pattern languages that are similar to the shell's filename globbing patterns, such as the patterns used in SQL queries with `LIKE`. These are all quite simple and generally provided as a convenient way of matching bits of strings. Regular expressions are, in comparison, a whole lot more complex.

---

You mention "`bash` regular expressions".  The `bash` shell *does* support regular expressions, but not for filename matching.  Within `[[ ... ]]`, the `=~` operator performs a regular expression match of the string on the left hand side against the regular expression on the right.  The type of regular expressions that the `bash` shell supports in this way are the standard extended set of regular expressions. See the `bash` manual on your system for further information about this.

Comment: Kusalananda, what is implicitly anchored? Encapsulates a behavior? I guess.

Comment: @user9303970 Regular expressions may be anchored to the start or end of a line using `^` and `$` respectively ("explicitly"). A filename globbing pattern is always anchored to the start and end of a string.  The pattern `a*b` will not match the filename `abba`, for example, because the `b` in `a*b` _has to_ occur at the end (it is "implicitly" anchored to the end).  In contrast, the regular expression `a.*b` will match `abba`, because the `b` isn't anchored to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Globs and regular expressions are two distinct pattern languages. The fact that there is some overlap in the semantics of certain patterns doesn't mean that one is necessarily a "dialect" of the other. Everybody who has used both recognize the similarity, but keeping the names distinct reduces the possibility for confusion.

On a related note I find it unfortunate that so many types of regular expressions (at least basic, extended, and Perl with variations) have very similar names. Most people in my experience do not qualify which one they mean, sometimes causing unnecessary confusion. If these flavours had been given much more distinct names it might have been easier to talk about them without misunderstandings.